# Why is the size of the bit-field structure different from what I think?

Tags: g++

everyone here.
In my opinion, the calculation below is correct.
1byte(8bit)
2byte(16bit)
2byte(16bit)
3byte(24bit)
= 8byte(64bit)
However, when I checked using sizeof in Windows and Ubuntu environments, I returned 10 bytes.
I'm so curious about the reason.

version g++ 11.4.0
ubuntu 22.04, windows

```
struct request{
unsigned char bit_a:1;
unsigned char bit_b: 2;
unsigned char bit_c: 1;
unsigned char bit_d:4;
unsigned short bit_short_a;
unsigned short bit_short_b;
unsigned char bit_arr\[3\];
};
std::cout \<\< sizeof(request) \<\<std::endl;

Expected output
8
Actual output
10
```